# SQL case subquery + subquery > 0

Tags: mysql, sql, case

i am trying to devide a number with another number. but because there is a chance that the result is 0 i want to make a case saying that if it is 0 then it should be 1 for this ive created this:

```
(CASE(SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM module_score 
     WHERE user_id = 40 AND medal_id > 1) 
+ 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM user_has_module_score uhms 
     WHERE user_id = 40 and medal_id > 1)> 0 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0 END) as passed_percentage
```

However i get the following syntax error:

```
medal_id > 1)> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as passed_percentage  
FROM system_learningbank.user U 
WHERE U.id = 40 GROUP BY U.id
```

`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as passed_percentage  FROM system_learningbank.user U WH' at line 7`

So what is the right syntax if to validate that it is not 0? and in my above example i set the variable to 1 but that should be the actual count of the subqueries

**My full sql statement**

```
    SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            module_score MS
        WHERE
            user_id = 40) + (SELECT 
            COUNT(UHMS.score)
        FROM
            user_has_module_score UHMS
        WHERE
            UHMS.user_id = 40) / ((SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            module_score
        WHERE
            user_id = 40 AND medal_id > 1) + (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            user_has_module_score uhms
        WHERE
            user_id = 40 and medal_id > 1) > 0) as passed_percentageas
FROM
    system_learningbank.user U
WHERE
    U.id = 40
GROUP BY U.id;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `when`:

```
(CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM module_score WHERE user_id = 40 AND medal_id > 1) +
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_has_module_score uhms WHERE user_id = 40 and medal_id > 1) > 0
      THEN 1 ELSE 0
 END) as passed_percentage
```

MySQL treats booleans as integers, so you can actually write this without the `case`:

```
( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM module_score WHERE user_id = 40 AND medal_id > 1) +
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_has_module_score uhms WHERE user_id = 40 and medal_id > 1) > 0
) as passed_percentage
```

EDIT:

```
   SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM module_score MS
           WHERE user_id = 40
          ) +
          (SELECT COUNT(UHMS.score)
           FROM user_has_module_score UHMS
           WHERE UHMS.user_id = 40
          ) / ((SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM module_score
                WHERE user_id = 40 AND medal_id > 1
               ) +
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM user_has_module_score uhms
                WHERE user_id = 40 and medal_id > 1
               ) > 0
              ) as passed_percentageas
FROM system_learningbank.user U
WHERE U.id = 40
GROUP BY U.id;
```

I suspect you want something more like this:

```
   SELECT ((ms.cnt + hms.cnt) /
           (case when ms.cnt_m1 + hms.cnt_m2 > 0 then ms.cnt_m1 + hms.cnt_m2 end)
          ) as passed_percentageas
FROM system_learningbank.user U left join
     (select userid, count(*) as cnt, sum(medal_id > 1) as cnt_m1
      from module_score
      group by user_id
     ) ms
     on ms.user_id = u.user_id left join
     (select userid, count(*) as cnt, sum(medal_id > 1) as cnt_m1
      from user_has_module_score
      group by user_id
     ) hms
     on hms.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE U.id = 40;
```

However, this still looks suspicious . . . the table names suggest that only one really codes the score you want, the denominator is more restrictive than the numerator, but this structure is basically what you seem to want.
    GROUP BY U.id;

Comment: So if it is >0 then it will count the right number or will et return 1?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen . . . It will return 1.  I'm not sure what the "right number" is.  This code returns 0 and 1, just as your code seems intended to do.

Comment: this returns null where it should return 2 What i want is when the case is > 0 then it should return what the case is else it should return 1 ive posted my full sql statement

Comment: @MarcRasmussen . . . This shouldn't be returning `NULL`.  `COUNT(*)` will return `0` if there are no matches, so nothing is ever `NULL`.  Perhaps you should edit your question and put in the full query that is returning `NULL`.

Comment: ive added my full sqlstatement

Comment: thank you so much for your help but this still returns null :S?

Comment: When checking the variables i get the following row:


cnt  cnt    cnt_m1 cnt_m2, passed_percentageas
'3', NULL, '1', NULL, NULL